# Visibly Moving JProgressBar

Tags: java, swing, event-dispatch-thread, jprogressbar, thread-sleep

I have a JProgressBar and want to be able to see it dynamically updated. The progress bar should be able to **visibly** move from one position to another, not just **change** without the bar visibly changing (think regular loading bars).

```
 public static void dropHPBar(int before, int after) {

    Thread.currentThread.sleep(50);

    while (before > after) {

        try {
            Thread.sleep(50);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        GameMain.gW.setHP(before);

        b --;
    }
```

and from GameMain.gW:

```
public void setHP(int x) {

    hpBar.setValue(x);
}
```

Why is the progress bar not being visibly updated?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Calling `Thread.sleep` in the [`EDT`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html) (*event dispatch thread*) prevents UI updates. You need to use [Swing Worker](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html) in order to archive proper [concurrency](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html).

From the Oracle website:

> Swing consists of three kinds of threads:
>
> - Initial threads, the threads that execute initial application code.
> - The event dispatch thread, where all event-handling code is executed. Most code that interacts with the Swing framework must also
>     execute on this thread.
> - Worker threads, also known as background threads, where time-consuming background tasks are executed.
>
> Tasks on the event dispatch thread must finish quickly; if they don't,
>   unhandled events back up and the user interface becomes unresponsive.